# Regex parsing multi-language string with languages codes

Tags: php, regex

I have multi-language strings formatted as follows:

> [en]this is english [es]esto es español [fr] C'est française [it] Questo è italiano

The order of the languages is not always the same, and not all languages are always available.

I'm trying, with no success, to extract a specific language string. Language strings contain HTML, and any sort of special characters, spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.

Let's say I want to extract the English part; I need a regex able to match everything after the [en] part (new lines, carriage returns, special characters, tabs, etc.) until the starting of a new language string: ([a-z]{2})

This is not working: the french string is also returned, and if the Spanish string is in the past position nothing is returned.

```
/\[es\]((.|\n|\t|\r)*)(\[([a-z]{2})\])/u
```

I'm not able to write a regex for: "anything after [es] that is not two letters inside brackets or end of string"

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FrankieTheKneeMan wrote a good explanation of the difference between greedy and lazy behaviour.

To take advantage of the greedy behaviour without backtracking (or with a very limited backtracking), you can use a negated character class:

```
/\[es]([^[]*)/u
```

*(note that you don't need the s modifier, since you don't use the dot.)*

**In case**: However, the precedent pattern doesn't allow the use of the opening square bracket inside the content you want to match. You can solve this problem if you check that each `[` is not the begining of a language tag:

```
/\[es]((?>[^[]+|\[(?![a-z]{2}]))*)/u
```

Answer (score 5):

Your real problem is greedy matching.  There're a couple ways to deal with that.  Lazy matching:

```
/\[es\]((?:.|\n|\t|\r)*?)\[([a-z]{2})\]/u
```

And negative lookaheads:

```
/\[es\]((?:(?!\[([a-z]{2})\])(?:.|\n|\t|\r))*)/u
```

You see, the Regex engine is **greedy**, which means it captures as many tokens as possible and **backtracks** until it has a matching string - the common way of saying is that the engine returns the largest capture possible.  You can use a **lazy** matcher (any matcher followed by a `?` - so `??`, `*?`, `+?`, etc), which inverts the matching behaviour and captures as little as possible, slowly grabbing more until it has a match.  You can also use a lookahead to ensure that the wildcard you're matching doesn't include your delimiter string.

You can also use the `s` modifier to force the . to match everything, including the newline character (it already matches the `\t` character.

```
/\[es\](.*?)\[([a-z]{2})\]/su
```

A word of caution to this tale, <strike>if Hercules fights, you will fail!</strike> if your string ever has anything in it that looks like a language code, but isn't - this regex will fail.

[Click here to see it match.](http://regexr.com?37fvn)

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation. Anyway I preferred the @CasimiretHippolyte answer because it matches also languages strings in the last position.